# How download make and set "make" as a command?

Tags: makefile

I went onto the GNU website to download make. I went to the main [GNU FTP server](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/) to choose one to download. I chose `make-4.1.tar.gz` and extracted the files.

I was not sure what to do from there so I went to the folder that was created from extracted the files and ran `./configure` hoping it would do something I wanted. I'm still not sure what it did.

When I run `make` from the command line it says `make: command not found`. Did I download make correctly and what do I have to do to get it to see `make` as a command?

I'm on Windows.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If it's windows you're best option is probably to just get all the GNU build utils pre-packaged in something like MiniGW

Comment: After `./configure`, you have to run `make`. But, since you don't have `make`, you can't... I'm assuming this is on Linux -- you'd be much better off just installing it using your distro's default package manager (something along the lines `sudo apt-get install make` or `yum install make` or whatever.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant "But, since you don't have make, you can't" Sure you can: `sh ./build.sh` followed by `./make install`.

Comment: @admdrew original advice still holds (sorry, I don't have all the non-conventional build files memorized for every major piece GNU software.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It's in the README file.

Comment: @PeterT I'm on Windows.

Comment: @MemyselfandI As PeterT alludes to, [just use MinGW](http://superuser.com/a/405160).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Linux, the README file that has these instructions:

> If you need to build GNU Make and have no other 'make' program to use,
>   you can use the shell script 'build.sh' instead.  To do this, first
>   run 'configure' as described in INSTALL.  Then, instead of typing
>   'make' to build the program, type 'sh build.sh'.  This should compile
>   the program in the current directory.  Then you will have a Make
>   program that you can use for './make install', or whatever else.

If you're on Windows, refer to README.W32 instead. It contains instructions to build make using MinGW and MSVC. However, you generally *don't* want to compile from source, and instead use a port that has already done that for you.

For example, if you intend to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/), [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) contains make. If you're using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), the installer allows you select it as a package. If you want a 64-bit MinGW distro that already comes with make and several other packages, such as the GNU coreutils, see [nuwen.net](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

The distro I mentioned above allows you to write commands like `gcc` and `make` without the annoying mingw32 prefix.

Comment: What's the difference between doing what the quote says and the part about gnu utilities and cygwin? Will it ultimately produce the same result?

Comment: @MemyselfandI The quote assumes that you're on a Unix environment and that you intend to compile make from source. However, since you're on Windows, the alternative is to use a port instead.

Comment: I actually already downloaded MinGW a long time ago. But the make that it uses it called `mingw32-make.exe` (I have to type out that whole name every time). So I was looking for a program just called `make` so I wouldn't hsve to do that.

Comment: @MemyselfandI [How to set an alias in Windows Command Line?](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line)